# Is the Windows Experience Index calculation the same on Windows 7 and 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-experience-index

Is the Windows Experience Index score calculated the same way on Windows 7 and 8?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is the Windows Experience Index score calculated the same way on Windows 7 and 8?

No, it isn't.

The highest possible value in Windows 7 is `7.9`.

The highest possible value in Windows 8 is `9.9`.

> Are the scores given on Windows 7 and 8 the same all the way up to 7.9, or are they calculated differently?

They're calculated differently.

[Here](http://www.faqforge.com/windows/windows-experience-index-scale-changes-on-windows-8/) is a report from somebody whose WEI dropped from `4.6` to `4.2`.

Comment: My numbers have remained the same on Win 7 and Win 8. Logically shouldn't it increase?

Comment: @pratnala No, the score should remain the same across Windows Versions and time. A system that measures 5.0 now should also measure 5.0 in other OSs in an X amount of time from now. However, Microsoft has updated some parts of the WEI score calculation from time to time to reflect new discoveries (particularly in HDDs) and new hardware when this hardware was released during the mainstream phase of the OS in question. Nevertheless, the general idea is that the numbers stay the same provided you don't change the hardware.